# assign pointer from argv in function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, argv

I am trying to assign a pointer correctly from the programs `**argv`. When I assign `data` in the main function it works fine, but when I attempt to place that logic into a separate function it does not.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
void parse_args(char *argv[ ], unsigned char *data, *data_len,  *nprocs){

    data = (unsigned char *)argv[1];
    *data_len = strlen(argv[1]);
    *nprocs = atoi(argv[2]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char *data;
    int  data_len;
    int   nprocs; 

    // this doesnt work (for data)
    parse_args(argv, data, &data_len, &nprocs)

    // this works (for data)
    data = (unsigned char *)argv[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function needs to be passed a `char * []` (which is equivalent to a `char**` in an argument specification). You shouldn't specify the type when calling a function, that should have given you a compiler error (`char *` is not to be used here!)

```
// this doesnt work (for data)
parse_args(char *argv, data, &data_len)
```

must be replaced by

```
parse_args(argv, data, &data_len)
```

So, next, you pass a pointer `data` , but you pass that pointer by value, i.e. your `parse_args` gets a nice copy of that pointer (which, technically, is just an address stored in a variable), and then you modify that copy. You might want to pass it like `data_len`:

```
void parse_args(char *argv[ ], unsigned char **data, *data_len,  *nprocs){
..
parse_args(argv, &data, &data_len, &nprocs)
```

All in all, this doesn't seem to be a great attempt at argument parsing. There's lots of libraries out there to do that for you, and if you want to stay old-school, I'd recommend using `gengetopt`, which generates all the parsing code you need and has nice documentation.

Comment: Argh I didnt see the "address of" in front of data! Working now. If I had more time I would explore what you mentioned. @Marcus üller

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
data = (unsigned char *)argv[1];
```

modifies a local copy of `main`'s local `data`, because all parameters, including pointers, are passed by value. If you would like to modify `data` inside `main`, pass it by pointer (i.e. you need a pointer to pointer now):

```
void parse_args(char *argv[ ], unsigned char **data_ptr, int *nprocs) {
    ...
    *(data_ptr) = (unsigned char *)argv[1];
    ...
}
```

Comment: trying now @dasblinkenlight